# Weird behaviour from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote a query (this is the simplest form of that query)

```
declare @tbl1 table(name varchar(50))
declare @tbl2 table(name varchar(50))
declare @query varchar(600)
set @query = ''

insert into @tbl1
select 'a' union select 'b'  union select 'c'  union select 'd'  union select 'e'

insert into @tbl2
select '1' union select '2'  union select '3'  union select '4'  union select '5'

select 
 @query = 
 ' Go ' + 
 @query +
 tbl1.name + ' (' +
 substring(
 (
    select ', ' + tbl2.name
    from @tbl2 as tbl2
    for xml path('')
 ), 3, 5000) + ') '
from @tbl1 as tbl1

print @query
```

I was expecting a result like this

```
 GO a (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) GO  b (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  GO c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  GO d (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  GO e (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

But this mean query return this to me

```
 Go  Go  Go  Go  Go a (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) b (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) c (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) d (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) e (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Can somebody please explain this result to me I fail to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you disregard the details in the query part of the string, you are doing this:

```
@query = ' Go ' + @query + 't(...) '
```

as `@query` is empty from start, the first iterations is:

```
@query = ' Go ' + '' + 't(...) '
```

which is `' Go t(...) '`. Next iteration becomes:

```
@query = ' Go ' + ' Go t(...) ' + 't(...)'
```

which ends up as `' Go  Go t(...) t(...) '`.

As you see, the `Go` is added first in the string, and the query last, so you end up with all `Go` in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change it to

```
select 
 @query = 
 @query +
 ' Go ' +    
 tbl1.name + ' (' +
 substring(
 (
    select ', ' + tbl2.name
    from @tbl2 as tbl2
    for xml path('')
 ), 3, 5000) + ') '
from @tbl1 as tbl1
```